# grunt-jade Is it possible to include external files?

Tags: pug, gruntjs

I am using [grunt-contrib-jade](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade) and I want to produce an html from several jade files. For example, I want to have `footer.jade` file that outputs html footer so I can reuse it for multiple pages. I want to be able to insert it into the specific part of an html file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. It looks like I can use the 'include' command, but it is somehow removed from the current documentation.

index.jade

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    include head
    title Test
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="style.css")
  body
    p This is a test.
```

head.jade

```
meta(charset="utf-8")
meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge,chrome=1")
meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
```

This will include `head.jade` in `index.jade`.

Comment: also you can use `extends`. Jade docs is good to learn it all.